# Updating Spring from 3.0.x to 3.1.2 causes form select box to not display list tostring

Tags: java, spring, maven

Recently I upgraded Spring from 3.0.5 to 3.1.2.  Everything worked except on my forms all my select boxes are displaying enum values instead of the toString value that previously displayed.

My enum is:

```
public enum StateType {

    ALABAMA("AL", 1, "Alabama"),
          etc

    StateType(String abbreviation, int code, String displayText) {
        this.abbreviation = abbreviation;
        this.code = code;
        this.displayText = displayText;
    }

          public String toString() {
             return displayText;
          }
}
```

My Controller then has this:

```
    @ModelAttribute("stateList")
public static StateType[] populateStateList() {
    return StateType.values();
}
```

My form has this snippet:

```
<form:select path="state" id="state" items="${stateList}" style="width:12em" dojoType="dijit.form.FilteringSelect"/>
```

This all worked in 3.0.5.  For some reason the toString is never called in 3.1.2.  My select boxes on the screen show the enum Constant (ALABAMA).

Any ideas to what changed?  I use maven to keep track of my dependencies.  All I did to update was update my spring version constant.  Perhaps I need to update some other dependency?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented the following solution.  This was ok since I have a smaller project.  This might not be acceptable for large projects.

Added a getter for my enum:

```
public enum StateType { 

ALABAMA("AL", 1, "Alabama"), 
      etc 

StateType(String abbreviation, int code, String displayText) { 
    this.abbreviation = abbreviation; 
    this.code = code; 
    this.displayText = displayText; 
} 

public String getDisplayText() {
   return this.displayText;
}

      public String toString() { 
         return displayText; 
      }
```

}

On the form add this :

```
<form:select path="state" id="state" items="${stateList}" itemLabel="displayText" style="width:12em" dojoType="dijit.form.FilteringSelect"/>
```

This now works as expected.  Like I mentioned this work around might not be acceptable for large projects.